# Change colour of text when CTRL-C and CTRL-V are pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want change text of html text when CTRL-C and CTRL-V are clicked. I have this code that changes the text when CTRL-C is clicked but when I copy other text, the previous text doesn't change back to its original colour. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctrlDown = false,
    ctrlKey = 17,
    cmdKey = 91,
    vKey = 86,
    cKey = 67;

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = true;
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = false;
  });

  // Document Ctrl + C/V 
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var clip = document.getElementById("clipBoard");
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == cKey)) {
      navigator.clipboard.readText()
        .then(text => {
          clip.value = text;

          var sel = window.getSelection();
          var range = 0;
          if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
          }
          // Set design mode to on
          document.designMode = "on";
          if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
          }
          // Colorize text
          document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "red");
          // Set design mode to off
          document.designMode = "off";
        })
        .catch(err => {

        });
      console.log("Document catch Ctrl+C");
    }
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey)) {
      console.log("Document catch Ctrl+V");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter text here and copy</p>
<span id="content" contenteditable>Test words to copy and paste</span>
<br>
<br>
<p>This is the text in the clipboard</p>
<textarea id="clipBoard" readonly></textarea>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EvTheCOSCStudent/Lzh9f3co/68/) of the code. It will only work in Chrome (clipboard permissions)

Thanks!

Comment: The way you're doing is not wrong but not suited for what you want, you just change the color and move on, instead you need to keep track of selected text which you clean up before you color another text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can opt to reset the color, each time before applying the new color. See snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctrlDown = false,
    ctrlKey = 17,
    cmdKey = 91,
    vKey = 86,
    cKey = 67;

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = true;
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = false;
  });

  // Document Ctrl + C/V 
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var clip = document.getElementById("clipBoard");
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == cKey)) {
      navigator.clipboard.readText()
        .then(text => {
          clip.value = text;

          var sel = window.getSelection();
          var range = 0;
          if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
          }
          // Set design mode to on
          document.designMode = "on";
          if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
          }
          //reset all custom color edits
          $('font').removeAttr('color');
          // Colorize text
          document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "red");
          // Set design mode to off
          document.designMode = "off";
        })
        .catch(err => {

        });
      console.log("Document catch Ctrl+C");
    }
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey)) {
      console.log("Document catch Ctrl+V");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter text here and copy</p>
<span id="content" contenteditable>Test words to copy and paste</span>
<br>
<br>
<p>This is the text in the clipboard</p>
<textarea id="clipBoard" readonly></textarea>
```

Note: Tested only Chrome 78

Comment: You are a gem. This is exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can colour pasted (CTRL+V) text with this code?

Comment: @Eisenhiem I'm having a problem with the pasting function, think you could give me a hand?

Comment: Sure, what do you have so far? Could you share a codepen perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I have figured it out! :)