# Change the colour of pasted text

Tags: javascript, html

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981298/change-colour-of-text-when-ctrl-c-and-ctrl-v-are-pressed/58981683#58981683) a couple of days ago. I'm running into the problem where I cannot change the colour of the text I want to paste. The copy function works, and I want to do the same thing for pasted text. Change the most recent pasted text to green, and the rest of the text (other than the last copied text) to default colour.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <audio id="copy" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-21.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio id="paste" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-22.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="playCopy()">Copy Sound</button>
    <button onclick="playPaste()">Paste Sound</button>
    <p>Enter text here and copy</p>
    <span id="content" contenteditable>Test words to copy and paste</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>This is the text in the clipboard</p>
    <textarea id="clipBoard" readonly></textarea>
  </body>

</html>

<script>
function playCopy() {
    document.getElementById('copy').play();
}
function playPaste() {
    document.getElementById('paste').play();
}
</script>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ctrlDown = false,
    ctrlKey = 17,
    cmdKey = 91,
    vKey = 86,
    cKey = 67;

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = true;
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = false;
  });

  // Document Ctrl + C/V 
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var clip = document.getElementById("clipBoard");
    //copy
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == cKey)) {
      navigator.clipboard.readText()
        .then(text => {
          clip.value = text;
          document.getElementById('copy').play();

          var sel = window.getSelection();
          var range = 0;
          if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
          }
          // Set design mode to on
          document.designMode = "on";
          if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
          }
          //reset all custom color edits
          $('font').removeAttr('color');
          // Colorize text
          document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "red");
          // Set design mode to off
          document.designMode = "off";
        })
        .catch(err => {

        });
    }
    //paste
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey)) {
        document.getElementById('paste').play();
      var text = document.getElementById("clipBoard").value;
      text.id = pasted;
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EvTheCOSCStudent/Lzh9f3co/110/).
This will only work for Chrome, thanks!

Comment: you could just put a CSS in the < textarea> 

textarea{color:red!important}

Comment: I need the copied text to be red and the pasted text to be green, can I achieve this?

Comment: you can add a <span class="copied> and <span class="pasted >  tag and add assign colour by CSS